# Normal Operators: Retransform

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Consider a normal operator:
$$N:\mathcal{D}(N)\to\mathcal{H}:\quad N^*N=NN^*$$

Construct the operator:
$$Q:=(1+N^*N)^{-1}:\quad Z:=N\sqrt{Q}$$

By the previous proof:
$$Z\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}):\quad Z^*Z=ZZ^*$$

Construct the operator:
$$R:=1-Z^*Z:\quad W:=Z\sqrt{R}^{-1}$$

> Then one obtains:
>   $$N=W=Z\sqrt{1-Z^*Z}^{-1}$$
>
> Especially one has:
>   $$Z=\int\lambda\mathrm{d}F(\lambda):\quad F(\mathbb{D})=1\quad F(\mathbb{S})=0$$

How can I prove this from scratch?

Comment: the character was introduced in the (Swedish) original of this book: http://www.amazon.com/Linda-as-Murder-Backstrom/dp/0552778362

Comment: @WillJagy: What do you mean?

Comment: I thought the word backtransform was funny; that does not prevent it from being a commonly used word in mathematics, of course. Also, there is a new television series called Backstrom, based on the main character of that book.

Comment: More than 10 edits raises an automatic flag (and in the old times put the question on CW). Given that you post a lot of self-answered questions it might be a good idea to use [the sandbox](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/sandbox-for-drafts-of-long-complex-posts) when you are not sure about formatting.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Oh I'm sorry!! *(Didn't know it raises automatic flags.)* Sandbox, nice. Sounds like what I need. Thanks man!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Identity**

Regard dense elements:
$$\overline{\mathcal{D}N^*}=\mathcal{H}:\quad\varphi\in\mathcal{D}N^*$$

A calculation gives:
$$ZZ^*\varphi=NQN^*\varphi=NN^*Q\varphi$$

The operator is closed:
$$Q\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}):\quad NN^*=\overline{NN^*}\implies NN^*Q=\overline{NN^*Q}$$

By closed graph theorem:
$$\mathcal{D}(NN^*Q)=\mathcal{H}\implies NN^*Q\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$$

By uniform extension:
$$ZZ^*\restriction_{\mathcal{D}N^*}=NN^*Q\restriction_{\mathcal{D}N^*}\implies ZZ^*=NN^*Q$$

So on operator level:
$$R=1-NN^*Q=1-(1+NN^*)Q+Q=Q$$

And on operator level:
$$Z\sqrt{R}^{-1}=N\sqrt{Q}\sqrt{Q}^{-1}=N$$

Concluding identity.

**Support**

For the spectrum:
$$\|Z\|\leq1\implies r(Z)\leq1\implies\sigma(Z)\subseteq\overline{\mathbb{D}}\implies F(\overline{\mathbb{D}})=1$$

Define the function:
$$\eta\in\mathcal{B}(\overline{\mathbb{D}}):\quad\eta(\lambda):=1-|\lambda|^2$$

As it is bounded:
$$Z\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}):\quad\eta(Z)=1-Z^*Z=Q$$

So for the boundary:
$$\mathcal{N}\eta(Z)=\mathcal{N}Q=(0)\implies F(\mathbb{S})=F\{\eta=0\}=(0)$$

Concluding support.