# Spectral Measures: Existence

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

**Problem**

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Consider a normal operator:
$$N:\mathcal{D}(N)\to\mathcal{H}:\quad N^*N=NN^*$$

By the previous threads:
$$Z=N\sqrt{(1+N^*N)^{-1}}\quad N=Z\left(\sqrt{1-Z^*Z}\right)^{-1}$$

Especially one had:
$$Z=\int\lambda\mathrm{d}F:\quad F(\overline{\mathbb{D}})=1\quad F(\mathbb{S})=0$$

Define the function:
$$\eta\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{D}):\quad\eta(\lambda):=\frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{1-|\lambda|^2}}$$

Construct as measure:
$$E(A):=F_\eta(A):=F(\eta^{-1}A)$$

> Then one obtains:
>   $$N=\int\lambda\mathrm{d}F_\eta(\lambda)=:\int\lambda\mathrm{d}E(\lambda)$$

How can I prove this?

**Reference**

This builds up on: [Tranform](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1245387/79762), [Retransform](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1247356/79762)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Meanwhile I got it...*

Define the functions:
$$f(\lambda):=\lambda\quad \iota(\lambda):=\frac{1}{\lambda}\quad\chi(\lambda):=\sqrt{\lambda}\quad g(\lambda):=1-|\lambda|^2$$

As it was bounded:
$$Z\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}):\quad 1-Z^*Z=g(Z)$$

For compositions:*
$$\iota(\chi(g(Z))=(\iota\circ\chi\circ g)(Z)=:g'(Z)$$

By measurable calculus:
$$N=Z\sqrt{1-Z^*Z}^{-1}=f(Z)g'(Z)\subseteq(fg')(Z)=\eta(Z)$$

For normal extensions:
$$N\subseteq\eta(Z)\implies N=\eta(Z)$$

So one arrives at:*
$$N=\eta(Z)=\int\eta(\lambda)\mathrm{d}F(\lambda)=\int\lambda\mathrm{d}F_\eta(\lambda)=\int\lambda\mathrm{d}E(\lambda)$$

Concluding existence.

**See the thread: [Pushforward](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1365246/79762)*